# Prevent Flyout opening dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am using AppBarButton and based on one condition I want to execute either direct command on AppBarButton click or display flyout for additional input, the issue is if flyout is there in the appbar button it will always open when button clicks.

Is there any way I can decide where to allow Flyout to open or not.

```
 <AppBarButton x:Uid="Accept" Label="Accept"
                      ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Label, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
                      Icon="Accept"
                      Command="{Binding AcceptAppBarCommand}" 
                      behaviors:AppBarButtonBehavior.AllowFocusOnInteraction="True">
            <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                <Flyout Placement="Bottom" >
                    <StackPanel Width="200">
                        <PasswordBox Header="Enter password:"
                                     Password="{Binding Path=Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        <Button Margin="0 5 0 0" Content="Accept"
                                Command="{Binding AcceptCommand}">
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Flyout>
            </AppBarButton.Flyout>
        </AppBarButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally if a control derives from a *Button* class, the flyout is being showed automatically:

> A flyout attached to a button opens automatically when the user clicks the button. You don't need to handle any events to open the flyout.

This generally happens if you add your flyout to *Flyout* property. If you don't won't such behavior, then attach flyout by *FlyoutBase* or add it to resources:

```xml
<AppBarButton x:Uid="Accept" Label="Accept"
              ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Label, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
              Icon="Accept"
              Command="{Binding AcceptAppBarCommand}"
              Click="AppBarButton_Click"> <!-- for sample -->
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <Flyout Placement="Bottom" x:Key="myFlyout" >
            <StackPanel Width="200">
                <PasswordBox Header="Enter password:"
                             Password="{Binding Path=Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <Button Margin="0 5 0 0" Content="Accept"
                        Command="{Binding AcceptCommand}">
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Flyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</AppBarButton>
```

and show when needed:

```cs
private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // in command, click or anywhere else (in that change move to suitable resources)
    FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(sender as FrameworkElement);
}
```

If you are looking more information about building a helper class/methods to make it more MVVM friendly take a look [at Macrominevra blog post](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2015/01/15/how-to-open-and-close-flyouts-in-universal-apps-using-mvvm/), [Depechie's post](http://depblog.weblogs.us/2016/01/31/uwp-close-a-flyout-mvvm-way-with-uwp-xamlbehaviors/) and [Shawn Kendrot's](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2015/05/08/Creating-a-behavior-or-action-to-close-a-Flyout-from-a-control-within-the-Flyout.aspx).

Comment: This Ans will work but its solving issue through code behind, not through MVVM pattern.

Comment: @RahulSonone Even MVVM needs some code. Taking a look at your answer - are you sure this is because of the Style change, I suppose it's die to making content of flyout (Border) hidden - then it's simply not being shown. I've edited the answer and added some links which you may find usefull in case of the MVVM.

Comment: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2015/01/15/how-to-open-and-close-flyouts-in-universal-apps-using-mvvm/
is good one I can use it but for the time being style is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found one work around, through style.

Create styles in resources

```
<Page.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter" x:Key="_hiddenFlyoutStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="_flyoutBorderStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeHighBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutContentThemePadding}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMaxWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMaxHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

Apply style to flyout and border.

```
<AppBarButton x:Uid="Accept" Label="Accept"
                      ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Label, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
                      Icon="Accept"
                      Command="{Binding AcceptAppBarCommand}" 
                      behaviors:AppBarButtonBehavior.AllowFocusOnInteraction="True">
            <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                <Flyout Placement="Bottom" FlyoutPresenterStyle="{StaticResource _hiddenFlyoutStyle}">
                    <Border Visibility="{Binding DisplayFlyout, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" 
                            Style="{StaticResource _flyoutBorderStyle}">
                        <StackPanel Width="200">
                            <PasswordBox Header="Enter password:"
                                     Password="{Binding Path=Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            <Button Margin="0 5 0 0" Content="Accept"
                                Command="{Binding AcceptCommand}">
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Flyout>
            </AppBarButton.Flyout>
        </AppBarButton>
```

DisplayFlyout is a bool property in viewmodel to decide when to Display flyout.

Comment: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2015/01/15/how-to-open-and-close-flyouts-in-universal-apps-using-mvvm/, This one is also good with the help of attached property.